# SpecFlow Coded UI: Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests, specflow

I am using Coded UI & SpecFlow. I have used following template and earlier it was working fine from last 6 months.

https://github.com/aqdasiftekhar/SpecFlowCodedUI/

I am facing following issue from last two days when i try to regenerate feature file.

**Exception in Feature.CS File:**

```
We could not find a data exchange file at the path BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported! TechTalk.SpecFlow.Utils.CodeDomHelper (resolution path: TechTalk.SpecFlow.CodedUI.MsTest.SpecFlowCodedUITestGenerator)

Please open an issue at https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/
Complete output:
BoDi.ObjectContainerException: Multiple public constructors with same maximum parameter count are not supported! TechTalk.SpecFlow.Utils.CodeDomHelper (resolution path: TechTalk.SpecFlow.CodedUI.MsTest.SpecFlowCodedUITestGenerator)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.CreateObject(Type type, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath, RegistrationKey keyToResolve) at BoDi.ObjectContainer.TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.CreateObjectFor(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath) at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath, String name)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__5(ParameterInfo p)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.ResolveArguments(IEnumerable1 parameters, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.CreateObject(Type type, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath, RegistrationKey keyToResolve) at BoDi.ObjectContainer.TypeRegistration.Resolve(ObjectContainer container, RegistrationKey keyToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.CreateObjectFor(RegistrationKey keyToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath) at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve(Type typeToResolve, IEnumerable1 resolutionPath, String name)
at BoDi.ObjectContainer.Resolve[T](String name)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.TestGeneratorFactory.CreateGenerator(ProjectSettings projectSettings)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.Actions.GenerateTestFileAction.GenerateTestFile(GenerateTestFileParameters opts)

Command: C:\Users\aqdas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_4d3f9930\Extensions\5yaz3tdw.3ra\TechTalk.SpecFlow.VisualStudio.CodeBehindGenerator.exe
Parameters: GenerateTestFile --featurefile C:\Users\aqdas\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpF07B.tmp --outputdirectory C:\Users\aqdas\AppData\Local\Temp\2 --projectsettingsfile C:\Users\aqdas\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpF07A.tmp
Working Directory: C:\Users\aqdas\ProjectName\ProjectFolder\Project.TestFolder\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0\tools
```

**My config File is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section
       name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest"
      generatorProvider="TechTalk.SpecFlow.CodedUI.MsTest.SpecFlowCodedUITestGenerator, TechTalk.SpecFlow.CodedUI.MsTest"
      runtimeProvider="TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.MsTestRuntimeProvider, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

**Specflow Generator Code:**

```
namespace TechTalk.SpecFlow.CodedUI.MsTest
{
    using System.CodeDom;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.UnitTestProvider;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Utils;

    public class SpecFlowCodedUITestGenerator : MsTestGeneratorProvider
    {
        public SpecFlowCodedUITestGenerator(CodeDomHelper codeDomHelper)
            : base(codeDomHelper)
        {
        }

        public override void SetTestClass(TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.TestClassGenerationContext generationContext, string featureTitle, string featureDescription)
        {
            base.SetTestClass(generationContext, featureTitle, featureDescription);

            foreach (CodeAttributeDeclaration customAttribute in generationContext.TestClass.CustomAttributes)
            {
                if (customAttribute.Name == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute")
                {
                    generationContext.TestClass.CustomAttributes.Remove(customAttribute);
                    break;
                }
            }

            generationContext.TestClass.CustomAttributes.Add(new CodeAttributeDeclaration(new CodeTypeReference("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute")));
        }
    }
}
```

I have posted issue on GitHub Link https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1262

I am using

- Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.6.7
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1
- SpecFlow 2017.2.7 Extension
- Specflow 2.0.1 NuGet Package

I will be thankful to you if anyone can help me to fix this issue.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my Specflow version from 2.1 to 1.9 and it worked. this means specflow 1.9+ do not support coded ui when it comes with custom generator provide.